# Android Studio: Recyclerview is not automatically or consistently appearing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am beginner level in android studio recyclerview. I don't understand when I open the app in my emulator sometimes the recyclerview doesn't appear so I have to restart 1-2 times to make it appear again in my main activity.

When the recyclerview doesn't work sometimes:

[image]

It working when the recuclerview is like this:

[image]

## MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.animation.Animation;
 import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.thesis.heppie.R;
 import com.thesis.heppie.adapter.CategoryAdapter;
 import com.thesis.heppie.service.CategoryService;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements     View.OnClickListener{
 private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
 private Toolbar toolbar;
 private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
 private FloatingActionButton fab, fab1, fab2;
 private Animation fab_open, fab_close, rotate_forward, rotate_backward;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab1 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab1);
fab2 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
fab_close =     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
rotate_forward =     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_forward);
rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_backward);
fab.setOnClickListener(this);
fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
fab2.setOnClickListener(this);

initNavigationDrawer();
initViews();

}

private void initViews() {
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), CategoryService.getAllCategory(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}




public void initNavigationDrawer() {

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                Intent h = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(h);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;
            case R.id.mymeals:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Meals", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;
            case R.id.calories:

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calories.class);
                startActivity(i);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;
            case R.id.logout:
                finish();

        }
        return true;
    }
});
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView tv_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(v);
    }
};
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
int id = v.getId();
switch (id) {
    case R.id.fab:

        animateFAB();
        break;
    case R.id.fab1:

        Log.d("FAB", "Fab 1");
        break;
    case R.id.fab2:

        Log.d("FAB", "Fab 2");
        break;
}
}

public void animateFAB(){

if(isFabOpen){

    fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
    fab1.startAnimation(fab_close);
    fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
    fab1.setClickable(false);
    fab2.setClickable(false);
    isFabOpen = false;
    Log.d("FAB", "close");

} else {

    fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
    fab1.startAnimation(fab_open);
    fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
    fab1.setClickable(true);
    fab2.setClickable(true);
    isFabOpen = true;
    Log.d("FAB","open");

}
}
```

## CategoryAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.thesis.heppie.activity.Recipe;
import com.thesis.heppie.model.Category;
import com.thesis.heppie.R;

import java.util.List;

public class CategoryAdapter extends          RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Category> android;
private Context context;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> android) {
this.android = android;
this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
View view =     LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_main, viewGroup, false);
return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

viewHolder.txt_android.setText(android.get(i).getName());
Picasso.with(context).load(android.get(i).getImage()).resize(240, 120).into(viewHolder.img_android);
   View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int position = holder.getPosition();

        Category category = android.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext().getApplicationContext(), Recipe.class);
        i.putExtra("category", category.getName());
        view.getContext().startActivity(i);
    }
};
viewHolder.txt_android.setOnClickListener(clickListener); 
viewHolder.img_android.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

viewHolder.txt_android.setTag(viewHolder);
viewHolder.img_android.setTag(viewHolder);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return android.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
private TextView txt_android;
private ImageView img_android;
public ViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);

    txt_android = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_android);
    img_android = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);

}



}

}
```

## AppConfig

```
public class AppConfig {


public static String URL_GETCATEGORY = "http://10.0.2.2/heppie/getCourseType.php";
}
```

## Model

```
public class Category {

private String name;
private String image;


public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(String android_image_url) {
this.image = android_image_url;
}
}
```

## Service

```
public class CategoryService {


public  static List<Category> getAllCategory(Context context){
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

final List<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.URL_GETCATEGORY,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response); 
                    JSONArray result =  jObj.getJSONArray("result");
                    for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++){
                        Category category = new Category();
                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject)result.get(i); 
                        String name = (String) object.get("name"); 
                        String image = (String) object.get("image"); 
                        category.setName(name);
                        category.setImage(image);
                        list.add(category);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("That didn't work!", "asd");
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return super.getParams();
    }
};

queue.add(stringRequest);
return list;
}
}
```

## activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.thesis.heppie.activity.MainActivity">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="15dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/header_main"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/grey_bg"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
    </LinearLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB1"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>






</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## content_main

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
style="@style/RippleStyleWhite"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/black_bg"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_overlay">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_android"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Title"
                android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

Can you help me guys ? Thanks !!!

Comment: A few more pieces of information will be helpful. The XML code for your activity and adapter. Also are any of your exception logs being reached? It may be that your network request to retrieve the list of items is failing, which means your RecyclerView is empty.

Comment: the problem is the way you're trying to load data from the internet. Stuff is getting executed in the service in a background thread and you're not properly passing the list back to the activity. The only reason it "sometimes" works is due to pure threading luck.

Comment: @Budius is correct. It might be better to rethink your logic. Maybe create your RecyclerView with an empty list, then get your data afterwards from your service and update the list with the response.

Comment: @tjshakespeare I already edited my post with XML and preview. There no error logs appearing. I'm using WAMP for localhost to retrieve the list of items.

Comment: @Budius how can I proper pass the list back to the activity? I'm not that good with the recyclerview I'm just a newbie with it and I just took the logic from someone in the internet..... Hope you can help me this one....Thanks!

Comment: I've added a quick answer. It's not a great code, but should help get you moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way of fixing your code is change your method to:

```
 public static void getAllCategory(Context context, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        final List<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.URL_GETCATEGORY,
                listener, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("That didn't work!", "asd");
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return super.getParams();
            }
        };

        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

and then on your activity you implement the listener, like this:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener,
    Response.Listener<String> {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response); 
                JSONArray result =  jObj.getJSONArray("result");
                for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++){
                    Category category = new Category();
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject)result.get(i); 
                    String name = (String) object.get("name"); 
                    String image = (String) object.get("image"); 
                    category.setName(name);
                    category.setImage(image);
                    list.add(category);
                }
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(this, list));             
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but remember that even thou this will work , and should get you started on what means to have callbacks, it's not a good proper production code.
            }

Comment: So far I am having errors(double asterisk indicated) in the Activity: `CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), CategoryService.getAllCategory(**this**));` - error:Categoryservice cannot be applied to Mainactivity  and here.......`**list**.add(category);
            }
           ** recyclerView**.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(this, **list**));` - error: cannot resolve symbol.